# image does not show in extjs render function

Tags: extjs

I am trying a renderer function like this:

```
pdfRenderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
return String.format('<a href="#" onclick="openPdf({0},{1})"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/images/pdf_icon.gif"/></a>',arg1,arg2);

    }
```

The problem is that the pdf icon does not show. If I put in a text in place of the img, it shows fine. What am I doing wrong here.(It works in none of the browsers)
I opened the icon separately and it can open in all browsers.

Comment: What is the return value of the String.format call?

Comment: It is :<a href="#" onclick="openPdf({0},{1})"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/images/pdf_icon.gif"/></a> with the {0} and {1} substituted. Why request.getContextPath() is not evaluated? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If does not show up there is problem with link.

Try to place just link instead image:

```
pdfRenderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){ 
  return String.format('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/images/pdf_icon.gif',arg1,arg2);
  }
```

result will show you what problem with link is

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is some problem with resolving scriptlet expressions '<%=request.getContextPath()%' from inside a javascript function.
For now, I solved it using :
Declar a hidden variable in jsp when it loads
input type = 'hidden' id = 'hidVar' value = ' <%=request.getContextPath()%>/static/images/pdf_icon.gif'

In the renderer function:
pdfRenderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
var url = document.getElementById('hidVar').value;
return String.format(url,arg1,arg2);
    }